# Multiple category scatter plot in dash plotly

Tags: plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am new to Dash and dashboard development generally and I ran into the following issue.
So, here are the contents of an example DataFrame that I am working with:

```
data = {
    'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'orange'],
    'value1': [30, 35, 11, 57, 47, 93],
    'value2': [1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 7]
}
```

What I'd like to achieve, is to create one scatter plot that will show all of those items (i.e. color in this example) in a single plot.
Looking at the open source Dash examples, this is achieved manually by calling `go.Scatter` multiple times, [see code example here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/master/apps/dash-multipage-report/app.py#L338-L369).

How can I achieve this programmatically and not having to call `go.Scatter` a gazillion times? The content of my DataFrame is dynamic, so I cannot even have static code.

The exact same question has been asked elsewhere ([Multiple Line Charts](https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-line-charts/31572)) but the answer suggests using plotly.express which is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: While it is an excelent practice to provide sample data, in this case the sample data provided does not match the example code. Also it is aways better to snip the relevant piece of code in the question rather than linking to it.

Comment: You can just automate it by yourself. You just need to create an array of go.Scatter elements.